# How to Sort response Mongoose according to defined schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need help how to sorting response data according to schema.

This is my `schema`

```
const RoleModel = new Schema({
    name    : {...
    },
    description:{...
    },
    permission:{...
    }
},{timestamps: false})
```

and here my current response

```
{
  "message": "Displaying data",
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": {...
      },
      "_id": "615b378a3eca06e2194c2204",
      "name": "SuperAdmin",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "permission": {...
      },
      "_id": "615b396f3eca06e2194c220a",
      "name": "Reporter",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "permission": {...
      },
      "_id": "615b39dea1e3f384847014d1",
      "name": "Finance",
      "description": "nodescription",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I want the response data sorted like this

```
    "data" : [
    {
        "_id" :615b378a3eca06e2194c2204, // first key
        "name": superadmin, // second key
        "permission":{...}, // third key
        "__v": 0 // last key
    },
    {
        "_id" :615b378a3eca06e2194c2204, // first key
        "name": superadmin, // second key
        "permission":{...}, // third key
        "__v": 0 // last key
    }
    ...
]
```

Should I create a new variable with defined key object and assign each data to it or there is a right way to do it?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You can use `project` methodology in `find()` in *mongodb* to display how you want to.
Below I have the code for you:

```
db.studentdatas.find({},{_id:1, name:1, permission: 1, __v:1}).sort({name:1})
```

**1** in **find()** depicts you want that field to be seen/projected which is in **{}**.

You will not require sorting here. But if you want to sort data any field based on the data it has then you can use `sort()` either **1 or -1**.

And to display the data of response you can write in nodejs/expressjs:

```
res.send(response.data)
```

where your `response.data` is what you mentioned in your question :

```
 "data" : [
    {
        "_id" :615b378a3eca06e2194c2204, // first key
        "name": superadmin, // second key
        "permission":{...}, // third key
        "__v": 0 // last key
    },
    {
        "_id" :615b378a3eca06e2194c2204, // first key
        "name": superadmin, // second key
        "permission":{...}, // third key
        "__v": 0 // last key
    }
    ...
]
```

I hope this is what you wanted to ask.